# ZBarReaderViewController camera rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, rotation

Im using the Zbar SDK and i got an camera rotation issue. I've already read all topics about this issue but i can't resolve it.

My source :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    IBPUtils *utils = [[IBPUtils alloc] init];

    ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
    [reader setReaderDelegate:self];
    [reader setSupportedOrientationsMask:UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll];
    [reader setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [reader setWantsFullScreenLayout:NO];
    [reader setShowsCameraControls:NO];
    [reader setShowsZBarControls:NO];
    [reader.readerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cameraView.bounds.size.width, cameraView.bounds.size.height)];

    [cameraView addSubview:reader.view];
    [self setZbarReaderViewController:reader];
}
```

I put the "reader" in a subView of my principal view.

I tried to rotate the zbarview in the willRotateToInterfaceOrientation method
 but it doesn't work.

When the view is rotating, the zbarviewcontroller doesn't rotate.

The overlayView of the zbarcontroller doesn't rotate. 
I got an horizontal line and when i rotate the iPAD the horizontal line is vertical...

Any help ? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Add the following method in the view controller class

```
  - (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) orient
                                     duration: (NSTimeInterval) duration
    {
        [readerView willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: orient
                                            duration: duration]; 
    }
```

Here readerView is an object for ZBarReaderView. Hope this helps